# Check if remote file exists Linux

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I have following script that is used to check if file exists in remote Linux machine. Although it works when directly invoked on console, it does gets me prompt asking password when this script is invoked in Java via Runtime->exec()

```
`ssh $HOSTNAME test -f $FILENAME`       
    result=$?
    result=0;
    if [ $result != "0" ]; then
        echo "$FILENAME is not found"
        exit 31;
    fi
```

I have also used the script adding user name as

```
`ssh root@HOSTNAME test -f $FILENAME
```

Comment: You force `result` to be zero, indicating success, before you ever test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recheck your ssh keys and which user you're running as for Java. If the keys don't match then you'll be prompted for a user/password.

Comment: You are right, I have found out the problem. Actually when I have inspected the whole my linux script I have realized that HOST_NAME is set localhost somehow, Therefore url becomes root@localhost.